# What's my resolution?

Tags: resolution

What is the resolution of my Dell Inspiron E1505 if my laptop says the screen resolution is 1400x900? Is it 720p or more?

Comment: From stackExchange link I thought you were talking about new year resolutions, but I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 5):

Your (shorthand) resolution is **900p**.

Answer (score 4):

1080p and 720p refer to the second number or height. Historically, this comes from television resolutions, where there was less emphasis on the width and more on the height for whatever reason.  I'm sure [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/480i) could elaborate more on that.

Comment: Old analog TV did not have pixels horizontally, it was all sent completely analog.  What they had was a number of horizontal lines, which the *could* count.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John T, you'd have a `900p` resolution.

`900` means the number of pixels in any vertical column, i.e., the pixel height of the screen. The `p` part means it's progressively scanned or non-interlaced — that's a good thing and the case for all contemporary laptops as far as I know.

This shorthand resolution notation comes from the fact that horizontal resolution used to change across broadcasts and televisions, making it harder to standardize.